# WordPress main style to load first

Tags: wordpress

A WordPress website loads a lot of things before the main css file. The stylesheet was previously hard-coded in the head in the `header.php` file, I have enqueued it in the `functions.php` file, but it is possible to give this file priority now so it loads first before everything else? As it is now, it loads last and it's very visible for the users.

```
function twentyfourteen_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_style' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use dependency parameter in enqueue/register style function (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style). Set dependency on styles which you want to load after main style OR choose one first style after you can load main style as dependency.

EDIT: or add priority to your action

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_style', 1 ); // added 1 as priority 1, everything else will be loaded after this action
```